# Results of multiple foreach loops in one table in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I have multiple results of a foreach and I need to stick them into a table.

My current result is:

- The user Johnny is a trainer
- The user Mark is a trainer
- The user Bob is a footballer
- The user fred is a footballer
- The user Moe is a footballer

This comes from the foreach loops:

```
foreach ($user in $trainer)
{
Write-Host "The user $user.Name is a $user.Type"
#For email $body+= "The user " + $user.Name + " is a " + $user.Type +"<br/>"
}
```

And it goes on for all the types foreach `($user in $footballers)`,....

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a nice table sent to me by mail that looks kinda like this: 
[image]

How can I add results to a table from multiple for each loops in PowerShell?

Comment: Probably not, but if I were to guess I'd say it's due to the lack of [mcve] in your question.

Comment: thats straight BS in my opinion I did everything I could to explain my problem

Comment: Explaining the problem is important but not the only metric used to define value. I think the issue is that you _show_ writing text to console, incorrectly mind you, but you are asking for what appears to be a styled HTML table without actually trying to make one? There are many examples of converting objects to HTML which usually come up with `ConvertTo-HTML`

Comment: You didn't indicate that you tried anything to get the table you wanted. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written won't work correctly actually, you need to be using the sub-expression operator `$()` as follows in order to access the object properties:

```
Write-Host "The user $($user.Name) is a $($user.Type)"
```

It seems that `$trainer` is already an object with `Name` and `Type` properties so (outside of the `foreach` loop) it should be a simple case of doing:

```
$Body = $trainer | Select Name,Type | ConvertTo-HTML
Send-MailMessage -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml # other parameters, e.g to/from
```

Also if you have multiple objects that have the same properties, you could just combine them first with the addition operator:

```
$athlete = $trainer + $footballer
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm getting there with your method. However the layout is absolutely ugly. Is there a method to do something about the layout of the table?

Comment: That's what CSS was invented for.

Comment: You could also use the `-Head`  property of CovertTo-HTML to add a block of HTML that were HTML `Style` tags.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Mark